# Performance between unload vs sqlContext read

Tags: amazon-redshift

Please help me to get the optimized performance while reading data from redshift.

Option 1: I unload the data from table to a S3 folder and then read it as a dataframe

Optin 2: I use sqlContext read.

My Data volume is currently less but expected to grow in coming months so when i tried both options it takes almost the same time.

Option : 1

```
unload ('select * from sales_hist')   
to 's3://mybucket/tickit/unload/sales_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';

hist_output_table_df = spark.read.format(config['reader_format'])\
      .option('header', config['reader_header'])\
      .option('delimiter', config['reader_delimiter'])\
      .csv(s3_directory +  config['reader_path'])
```

reader_path is same as the directory as unloaded above.

Option : 2

```
 hist_output_table_df = sqlContext.read.\
                          format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
                          .option("url",jdbcConnection)\
                          .option("tempdir", tempS3Dir)\
                          .option("dbtable", table_name)\
                          .option("aws_iam_role",aws_role).load()
```

Is there a cost implication between the two approaches

Comment: how many rows/what size ? now vs future? what is the network connectivity of your client software? (network speed) ? how long does it take at the moment (seconds)

Comment: Current size is about 1-2 GB but in future it might grow to 20-25 GB. The network speed is about 15-20MbPS and currently it takes only 30-40 seconds

Comment: That sounds about right, you are probably completely bottle-necked by the network speed so it wont make any difference how you do it. option 1 or option will remain the same as each other and grow proportionately to the data size. if you are using ec2 you could upgrade your speed? Ideally you would re-think / re-architect the solution so that the data does not need to make this trip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark Redshift driver used by `sqlContext` does an `UNLOAD` behind the scenes. That's why you must provide a `tempS3Dir` - that's where it unloads to.

So the performance will be roughly the same but I would suggest using `sqlContext` because it is more encapsulated.